# Deleted nvm now npm is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, package, controls, nvm

I installed nvm to update my node but then decided to uninstall. After updating my node via website, I am not able to get npm installed despite installing a new version of node and using:

`sudo curl -L npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

Here is the message I am getting:
`-bash: /Users/SICNARF/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin/npm: No such file or directory`

I think I just have to change the command from non-existing nvm directory to (wherever its supposed to run).

Comment: Have you tried `which npm`?

Comment: yes nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js version management: no subshells, no profile setup, no convoluted API, just simple.

Installation

```
npm install -g n
```

Example

```
$ n 8.2.1
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/n